# Changing Tables in Highcharts Missing Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

**I have an HTML table with some data, from that table I'm creating a chart:**

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('graph_user_1', {
    data: {
        table: 'table_user_1',
        startColumn: 0,
        endColumn: 1
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Coverage'
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Hours'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.y + ' Points - ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            colorByPoint: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        id: 'series1'
    }],
    colors: [
        '#ff0000',
        '#00ff00',
        '#0000ff',
        '#3A8BEE',
        '#F9B342',
        '#DC4008'
    ]
});
```

**I also have a filter, it lets me select some dates and filter the table, these rows of data that are not hidden, are appended to a hidden table on the page:**

```
$("#to_date").on("change", function() {
    var from = parseDate($('#from_date').val());
    var to = parseDate($('#to_date').val());
    var loop_count = 0;
    var hidden_count = 0;
    $("#body tr").each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var date_from = parseDate(row.find("td").eq(7).text());
        var date_to = parseDate(row.find("td").eq(8).text());
        var show = true;
        show = isContained(date_from, date_to, from, to);
        if (show) {
            row.show();
            legendArray.push(row); //pushes row to array
        } else {
            row.hide();
            hidden_count++;
        }
        loop_count++;
    });
    if (hidden_count === loop_count) {
        warning.prop("hidden", false);
        warning.append("<strong>No results.</strong>");
    }
    restore(legendArray, chart);
});
```

**The restore function at the end gets the array with rows and a chart reference, it appends the rows from the array to the new table, then changes the source of the data from the original to the hidden table (id="aux") and redraws it.**

```
function restore(array) {
var table = document.getElementById('auxBody');
for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
    table.appendChild(array[i][0].cloneNode(true));
}
var complete = function(options) {
    var chart = $('#graph_user_1').highcharts();
    var series1 = chart.get('series1');
    series1.setData(options.series[0].data, false);
    chart.redraw();
};

Highcharts.data({
    table: 'aux',
    complete: complete
});
```

}

**After this, the graph IS updated, but it's always missing one row, the last one. I've printed the array, the new table, the nodes that are being appended, inspected, etc. All of this show the table with all the rows, but the graph is always missing the last one, I thought it was an index problem in the loop that adds the nodes but that doesn't seems to be the case.**

Comment: can you reproduce the problem and share it ? use jsfiddle or similar services or add code snippet in stackoverflow

Comment: @NidhinChandran I'm on that.

Also, by parsing the columns and printing the data in them, I can tell that the "name" property takes the value of the row not showing, so It could be a header issue, even though I did added a fake head to the hidden table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted earlier, it was a header issue with the table.
At creation I was appending the outerHTML of the copied table head:

```
newTable.append(newTHead[0].outerHTML);
```

Of course this caused an issue and the table had no headers, (even though it still showed on inspect) solution was removing the outerHTML and just appending the node, just a dumb conceptual mistake.

```
newTable.append(newTHead[0]);
```